# Navbar size changed to vertical after inserting Bootstrap Carousel (still not working after fixing for few days)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, django-templates, carousel

On my index.html, my navbar changed to vertical after inserting Bootstrap carousel.

I tried changing everything I could, like the font size, width, etc.
But it seems like it is the problem of the carousel itself. Once I import the library using this line of code: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`, the navbar will automatically resize into vertical, but if I comment this line out, the navbar becomes normal again but the carousel function will then not work.

How can I fix it to make it looks like other pages. (Navbar on top and horizontally)

For the navbar, I've got a base.html that basically the code for the navbar, and it is extended in everypage.

[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dur1C.png)

[image]

**index.html**

```
{% extends "morse_logs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<title>Home</title>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .carousel{
            background: #2f4357;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .carousel-item{
            min-height: 20px; /* Prevent carousel from being distorted if for some reason image doesn't load */
        }
        .bs-example{
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide col-sm-12" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{% static 'morse_logs/img/X.jpg' %}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{% static 'morse_logs/img/Y.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{% static 'morse_logs/img/Z.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**
This is the file for my navbar

```
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <div class="container ">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #2d2d30; font-size: 18px !important; font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'morse_logs:index' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> Morse Code App</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:index' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:tutorialIndex' %}">Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:gameDirectory' %}">Game</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:cipher' %}">Cipher</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:decipher' %}">Decipher</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'users:view_profile' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile </a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out </a></li>
                {% else %}
                  <li><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'users:register' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Register</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>

<body>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm6 col-sm-offset-3">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**gameDirectory.html**
normal webpage layout

```
{% extends "morse_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'morse_logs/css/style.css' %}">
<div class="container">
    <title>Game Index</title>
    <h1>GAME INDEX</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'morse_logs:game1' %}">Game 1</a>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely there is a small HTML syntax error in base.html. Currently, you have included bootstrap navigation outside the body tag.

Replace the base.html file with the following code:

```
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container ">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
            style="background-color: #2d2d30; font-size: 18px !important; font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;">
            <div class="container-fluid ">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'morse_logs:index' %}"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> Morse Code App</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:index' %}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:tutorialIndex' %}">Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:gameDirectory' %}">Game</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:cipher' %}">Cipher</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'morse_logs:decipher' %}">Decipher</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:view_profile' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Profile </a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out
                            </a></li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:register' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                Register</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>


    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm6 col-sm-offset-3">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The index page layout is still the same, after I changed the base html

Comment: Check for HTML syntax errors in your compiled code. Make sure to include all other code after the <head> tag and also if bootstrap is loaded. If you have it hosted somewhere, feel free to share the link so I can inspect it further.

Comment: https://github.com/phl6/morse_log 
this is where I put the code, thank you

Comment: I think bootstrap is loaded here and all the code are included, but still the problem remains the same.

Comment: Here's a codepen link https://codepen.io/nigeldcruz/pen/BaooVPN of a working bootstrap carousel and fixed navigation. I suggest you first copy the code in your index.html file. Once that is working, you should integrate it.
I checked the GitHub repo but it didn't have a readme.md file. It's always a good idea to have one with a brief summary of the project and set up instructions. Let me know if the codepen helps :)

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't work as expected, I think it is because of this line of code: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">, which activates bootstrap, once I comment it out, the navbar will be fine, but the carousel will also disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211653/discussion-between-nigeldcruz-and-din).